# How can I take backspace character in a char array in C language and execute an IF condition on basis of Backspace Character?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, fgets

My sample code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LIMIT 20 
int main() 
{ 
 char str[10]; 
 printf("\nEnter any character");
 fgets(str, 10, stdin);
 ***if(str[0] == '\b'){
    "Function call here"
    printf("\nbackspace is entered");*** 
 printf("%s", str);
 //Below part is for string to int conversion// 
 int integer;
 sscanf(str, "%d", &integer);
 printf("\nNew integer is %d",integer);

 return 0;
```

My main problem is in the if condition .... Please guide me....I'll be very thankful to all of you

Comment: Your problem is *not* the if condition.  The problem (I suspect) is that the tty is doing a lot of buffering for you and not actually passing the backspace character to your program.

Comment: i didn't get your annswer...  what's tty....?

Comment: A tty is the device that you use to interact with the program.  If you are running an interactive shell, it is running inside a tty.  If you type "foobaz<backspace>r", the tty interprets the keystrokes and sends "foobar" to your program.

Comment: regarding: `fgets(str, 10, stdin);
 ***if(str[0] == '\b'){`   the `stdin` stream is 'normally' 'cooked'  Therefore, a `\b` will NEVER be seen by the program.  (you could change the `stdin` I/O mode to `raw` (much to long to go into making that change in a comment)  Then your program would see everything typed at the keyboard, However, `stdin` always starts as 'cooked'

Answer (score 0):

In [*canonical* mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html) of terminal drivers (also known as "cooked" mode), control characters are processed before being passed to the program. See [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) for more information.

You can however, disable the control chars you are interested. For example, you can disable DEL to get backspaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct termios old;
    /* Get current settings. */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old);

    struct termios new = old;
    new.c_lflag = ICANON;
    /* Disable DEL. */
    new.c_cc[VERASE] = 0;

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new);

    char str[10] = {0};
    printf("\nEnter:");
    fgets(str, 10, stdin);
    if(str[0] == 127) {
        printf("backspace is entered\n");
    }

    /* Restore old settings. */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old);
}
```

Comment: Sir.... termios.h is not found by the compiler as it saying 
"No such file or directory is found"...... how to install this header file of termios.h as I'm working on Dev C++ 5.11 version on Windows

Comment: `<termios.h>` is a POSIX header. It may not be available on non-POSIX systems. I am not familiar with Dev C++. Is there any option to enable POSIX mode in it?

Comment: the `backspace` character is `0x08`, not `0x7F` so this answer needs a bit of correction

Comment: @user3629249 True, but typically backspace key is mapped to delete key (0x7F).